# Insert elements into an element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to create a ToDo list with JQuery. I'd like to add a checkbox into each `<li>` element.

My code is:

```
$('ul').append($('<li>')
               .attr('id', '' + counter + '')
               .addClass('todo')
               .append(text))
       .append('<input type="checkbox" />');
```

this appends a checkbox after the li element but not in it. How do I insert the checkbox directly into the li element?

Comment: because you need to append it to the li, not the ul, checkboxes as direct descendants of ul is not valid

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

what your code did, is to add the checkbox into the **ul** element instead of the **li** element.

try:

```
var $li = $('<li />').attr('id', counter).addClass('todo').append('<input type="checkbox" />').append(text);
$('ul').append($li);
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the checkbox to the `li`, not `ul`.

```
  $('ul').append($('<li>')
           .attr('id', '' + counter + '')
           .addClass('todo')
           .append(text)
           .append('<input type="checkbox" />'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').append(
    $('<li />', {id : counter, 'class' : 'todo'}).append(
        text, $('<input />', {type: 'checkbox'})
    )
)
```

Comment: @AshishMishra, because you didnt define `text` in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QDA6M/1/

Comment: @AshishMishra - of course it's not, the variables aren't defined ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make code much more readable and easier to support. For example like this:

```
var $li = $('<li>', {
    id: counter,
    className: 'todo',
    text: text
})
.append('<input type="checkbox" />');

$('ul').append($li);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ter2/